# Groovy Mixin on Instance (Dynamic Mixin)

Tags: dynamic, groovy, instance, mixins

I'm trying to achieve following:

```
class A {
  def foo() { "foo" }
}

class B {
  def bar() { "bar" }
}

A.mixin B
def a = new A()

a.foo() + a.bar()
```

with one significant difference - I would like to do the mixin on the instance:

```
a.mixin B
```

but this results in

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: A.mixin() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [class B]
```

Is there a way to get this working like proposed in the [Groovy Mixins JSR](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GroovyJSR/Mixins)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this since Groovy 1.6

Call mixin on the instance metaClass like so:

```
class A {
  def foo() { "foo" }
}

class B {
  def bar() { "bar" }
}

def a = new A()
a.metaClass.mixin B

a.foo() + a.bar()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim! So I have to wait a bit till Groovy 1.7.1 is part of Grails (let's hope in 1.3)...

Comment: Just tried it out, and it works in 1.6.3 as well (which I believe is the version of groovy that grails 1.2 uses) :-)

Comment: Yes, this feature was added in Groovy 1.6
http://www.infoq.com/articles/groovy-1-6