# Adding a specific Trait to a Class at runtime

Tags: scala

I have a trait "Foo" with some methods. I want to mix this trait to any class. But I dont want to write something like

```
val b = new Bar with Foo
```

I need something like where I just pass a class and it is mixed with Foo. I want to mix with this trait only i.e it is fixed that all classes should be mixed with Foo trait only.

```
val b = new Factory(Bar) //Factory returns instance with trait Foo
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254232/dynamic-mixin-in-scala-is-it-possible/3269452#3269452) but I am not convinced.

Something like this is possible in scala?

Comment: Are you passing the _type_ `Bar` or an _instance_ of `Bar` in that factory example? If the latter, it is not possible, though implicit conversions are usually enough.

Answer (score 4):

The current best solution is to implement `Foo` something like this:

```
class Foo(bar:Bar) {
    ...
}
object Foo {
    def apply(bar:Bar) = new Foo(bar)
    implicit def backToBar = this.bar
}
```

Then use it as

```
val foo = Foo(myBar)
```

For any method names that are shared between `Foo` and `Bar`, the version in `Foo` will be used (as with overloading in a mixin).  Any other methods, the variant on `Bar` will be used.

The technique isn't perfect, methods in `Bar` will only ever call other methods defined in `Bar`, and never "overloads" defined in `Foo`.  Otherwise, it's pretty close to your needs.

Comment: i am new to scala but above code in interactive scala shell does not works, other thing Bar is variable i.e it can be (Bar with Foo) or (Boo with Foo), I did not get the above code, what it exactly does