# Mixing in a trait dynamically

Tags: scala, mixins, case-class, traits

Having a trait

```
trait Persisted {
  def id: Long
}
```

how do I implement a method that accepts an instance of any case class and returns its copy with the trait mixed in?

The signature of the method looks like:

```
def toPersisted[T](instance: T, id: Long): T with Persisted
```

Comment: It's an interesting question, but at the risk of stating the obvious, why are your case classes not extending a common trait that provides an id??

Comment: @virtualeyes It's an issue of a very fine tuned API of an ORM I'm working on. Until those objects implement this trait they are just business logic objects with no reference to db, but this approach opens a need for an API method like `def save[T](data: T): T with Persisted`, which would rely on the method described in the question.

Comment: ok, you have your reasons, but the answers to-date all indicate that in Scala you may have to rethink your approach. What ORM are you working with, one you have written, or 3rd party?

Comment: @virtualeyes It's a new ORM project I'm working on. I don't think it's impossible, I just think it's gonna be tough, probably will involve messing with bytecode. As soon as a solution comes up I'll post it or choose one here. Emil H made a nice suggestion I'll try to evolve on that.

Comment: ahhhh, the joys of rolling your own ;-) With Emil H's approach how would you, at compile time, do "new T with Persisted"? Seems like you would need a massive match {} statement (i.e. manually specify the target class), and then if that's the case, at that point why not just provide an id? Heh, heh, you'll figure it out, or give up and go with ScalaQuery ;-)

Comment: Funny that we all using Slick go through the very same issues and typesafe doesn't in their academic mindset react to provide a solution out of the box.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This can be done with macros (that are officially a part of Scala since 2.10.0-M3). [Here's a gist example of what you are looking for](https://gist.github.com/2559714).

1) My macro generates a local class that inherits from the provided case class and Persisted, much like `new T with Persisted` would do. Then it caches its argument (to prevent multiple evaluations) and creates an instance of the created class.

2) How did I know what trees to generate? I have a simple app, parse.exe that prints the AST that results from parsing input code. So I just invoked `parse class Person$Persisted1(first: String, last: String) extends Person(first, last) with Persisted`, noted the output and reproduced it in my macro. parse.exe is a wrapper for `scalac -Xprint:parser -Yshow-trees -Ystop-after:parser`. There are different ways to explore ASTs, read more in ["Metaprogramming in Scala 2.10"](http://scalamacros.org/talks/2012-04-28-MetaprogrammingInScala210.pdf).

3) Macro expansions can be sanity-checked if you provide `-Ymacro-debug-lite` as an argument to scalac. In that case all expansions will be printed out, and you'll be able to detect codegen errors faster.

edit. Updated the example for 2.10.0-M7

Comment: While this stuff is extremely intresting, it's also so hardcore. How am I gonna integrate these several compilation phases with Maven? Is it going to become any more approachable when the release gets here?

Comment: I think it will work with maven without problems, you can send compiler arguments : http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/example_compile.html . I have a working example with gradle based on expectify : https://github.com/flatMapDuke/TestMacro/commit/9a8949a1637ef967b9de45f31dd034d2506775a0. I am a bit impressed by the tree manipulation, but it's awesome :)

Comment: I agree, separate compilation is inconvenient. I'll see what I can do about that.

Answer (score 9):

It is not possible to achieve what you want using vanilla scala. The problem is that the mixins like the following:

```
scala> class Foo
defined class Foo

scala> trait Bar
defined trait Bar

scala> val fooWithBar = new Foo with Bar
fooWithBar: Foo with Bar = $anon$1@10ef717
```

create a `Foo with Bar` mixed in, but it is not done at runtime. The compiler simply generates a new anonymous class:

```
scala> fooWithBar.getClass
res3: java.lang.Class[_ <: Foo] = class $anon$1
```

See [Dynamic mixin in Scala - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254232/dynamic-mixin-in-scala-is-it-possible) for more info.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov You could also take a look at Autoproxy. https://github.com/scala-incubator/autoproxy-plugin/wiki but I'm unsure of it's current state.

Comment: You can expect a fully macro-based version to be available ready for the 2.11 release, hopefully I'll have it in time for RC1

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is known as record concatenation, something that Scala's type system does not support. (Fwiw, there exist type systems - such as [this](http://igitur-archive.library.uu.nl/math/2006-1220-202305/leijen_04_first_class_labels.pdf) and [this](http://www.impredicative.com/ur/) - that provide this feature.)

I think type classes might fit your use case, but I cannot tell for sure as the question doesn't provide sufficient information on what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Actually, [you can encode extensible records](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/records.scala) in Scala's type system, but that's not going to directly help with an answer to this question I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. We talked about it before.

Comment: Well, OK, but you said the exact opposite in your answer?

Comment: Such records _can be encoded_ in Scala. That is a different thing from them being a first class construct in the language.

Comment: You cannot concatenate classes/traits in Scala was what I meant. (I thought it was obvious from the context?)

Comment: In full generality? No. But you can concatenate tuples for example.

Answer (score 4):

## Update

You can find an up to date working solution, which utilizes a Toolboxes API of Scala 2.10.0-RC1 as part of [SORM](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/blob/d976aabfd4220aae976609e912128d3690f6f730/src/main/scala/sorm/persisted/PersistedClass.scala) project.

---

The following solution is based on the Scala 2.10.0-M3 reflection API and Scala Interpreter. It dynamically creates and caches classes inheriting from the original case classes with the trait mixed in. Thanks to caching at maximum this solution should dynamically create only one class for each original case class and reuse it later.

*Since the new reflection API isn't that much disclosed nor is it stable and there are no tutorials on it yet this solution may involve some stupid repitative actions and quirks.*

The following code was tested with Scala 2.10.0-M3.

### 1. Persisted.scala

The trait to be mixed in. *Please note that I've changed it a bit due to updates in my program*

```
trait Persisted {
  def key: String
}
```

### 2. PersistedEnabler.scala

The actual worker object

```
import tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain
import tools.nsc._
import reflect.mirror._

object PersistedEnabler {

  def toPersisted[T <: AnyRef](instance: T, key: String)
                              (implicit instanceTag: TypeTag[T]): T with Persisted = {
    val args = {
      val valuesMap = propertyValuesMap(instance)
      key ::
        methodParams(constructors(instanceTag.tpe).head.typeSignature)
          .map(_.name.decoded.trim)
          .map(valuesMap(_))
    }

    persistedClass(instanceTag)
      .getConstructors.head
      .newInstance(args.asInstanceOf[List[Object]]: _*)
      .asInstanceOf[T with Persisted]
  }


  private val persistedClassCache =
    collection.mutable.Map[TypeTag[_], Class[_]]()

  private def persistedClass[T](tag: TypeTag[T]): Class[T with Persisted] = {
    if (persistedClassCache.contains(tag))
      persistedClassCache(tag).asInstanceOf[Class[T with Persisted]]
    else {
      val name = generateName()

      val code = {
        val sourceParams =
          methodParams(constructors(tag.tpe).head.typeSignature)

        val newParamsList = {
          def paramDeclaration(s: Symbol): String =
            s.name.decoded + ": " + s.typeSignature.toString
          "val key: String" :: sourceParams.map(paramDeclaration) mkString ", "
        }
        val sourceParamsList =
          sourceParams.map(_.name.decoded).mkString(", ")

        val copyMethodParamsList =
          sourceParams.map(s => s.name.decoded + ": " + s.typeSignature.toString + " = " + s.name.decoded).mkString(", ")

        val copyInstantiationParamsList =
          "key" :: sourceParams.map(_.name.decoded) mkString ", "

        """
        class """ + name + """(""" + newParamsList + """)
          extends """ + tag.sym.fullName + """(""" + sourceParamsList + """)
          with """ + typeTag[Persisted].sym.fullName + """ {
            override def copy(""" + copyMethodParamsList + """) =
              new """ + name + """(""" + copyInstantiationParamsList + """)
          }
        """
      }

      interpreter.compileString(code)
      val c =
        interpreter.classLoader.findClass(name)
          .asInstanceOf[Class[T with Persisted]]

      interpreter.reset()

      persistedClassCache(tag) = c

      c
    }
  }

  private lazy val interpreter = {
    val settings = new Settings()
    settings.usejavacp.value = true
    new IMain(settings, new NewLinePrintWriter(new ConsoleWriter, true))
  }


  private var generateNameCounter = 0l

  private def generateName() = synchronized {
    generateNameCounter += 1
    "PersistedAnonymous" + generateNameCounter.toString
  }


  // REFLECTION HELPERS

  private def propertyNames(t: Type) =
    t.members.filter(m => !m.isMethod && m.isTerm).map(_.name.decoded.trim)

  private def propertyValuesMap[T <: AnyRef](instance: T) = {
    val t = typeOfInstance(instance)

    propertyNames(t)
      .map(n => n -> invoke(instance, t.member(newTermName(n)))())
      .toMap
  }

  private type MethodType = {def params: List[Symbol]; def resultType: Type}

  private def methodParams(t: Type): List[Symbol] =
    t.asInstanceOf[MethodType].params

  private def methodResultType(t: Type): Type =
    t.asInstanceOf[MethodType].resultType

  private def constructors(t: Type): Iterable[Symbol] =
    t.members.filter(_.kind == "constructor")

  private def fullyQualifiedName(s: Symbol): String = {
    def symbolsTree(s: Symbol): List[Symbol] =
      if (s.enclosingTopLevelClass != s)
        s :: symbolsTree(s.enclosingTopLevelClass)
      else if (s.enclosingPackageClass != s)
        s :: symbolsTree(s.enclosingPackageClass)
      else
        Nil

    symbolsTree(s)
      .reverseMap(_.name.decoded)
      .drop(1)
      .mkString(".")
  }

}
```

### 3. Sandbox.scala

The test app

```
import PersistedEnabler._

object Sandbox extends App {
  case class Artist(name: String, genres: Set[Genre])
  case class Genre(name: String)

  val artist = Artist("Nirvana", Set(Genre("rock"), Genre("grunge")))

  val persisted = toPersisted(artist, "some-key")

  assert(persisted.isInstanceOf[Persisted])
  assert(persisted.isInstanceOf[Artist])
  assert(persisted.key == "some-key")
  assert(persisted.name == "Nirvana")
  assert(persisted == artist)  //  an interesting and useful effect

  val copy = persisted.copy(name = "Puddle of Mudd")

  assert(copy.isInstanceOf[Persisted])
  assert(copy.isInstanceOf[Artist])
  //  the only problem: compiler thinks that `copy` does not implement `Persisted`, so to access `key` we have to specify it manually:
  assert(copy.asInstanceOf[Artist with Persisted].key == "some-key")
  assert(copy.name == "Puddle of Mudd")
  assert(copy != persisted)

}
```

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with macros, you can use the new toolboxes API that lets you compile ASTs and is guaranteed to be backwards compatible unlike interpreter. You can copy/paste my tree manipulation code and then use scala.reflect.mirror.mkToolBox().runExpr(...) to compile and run it.

Comment: Also, what exactly feels like black magic? Is it only the necessity to integrate with build tools, or it's something else?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Thank you very much for the suggestion on toolboxes, I'll definitely check it out! About black magic. It's that without decent tutorials or documentation it's very hard to get a grasp of what's going on. Also the API for building ASTs looks like being developed with a specific purpose of inflicting pain, though I can't say anything better about the reflection API either, but I get that it's all caused by the mixture with the compiler world. Having to manually manage the compilation process on top of that is just tooo much, I'd better leave that problem unsolved.

Answer (score -1):

While it's not possible to compose an object AFTER it's creation, you can have very wide tests to determine if the object is of a specific composition using type aliases and definition structs:

```
  type Persisted = { def id: Long }

  class Person {
    def id: Long = 5
    def name = "dude"
  }

  def persist(obj: Persisted) = {
    obj.id
  }

  persist(new Person)
```

Any object with a `def id:Long` will qualify as Persisted.

Achieving what I THINK you are trying to do is possible with implicit conversions:

```
  object Persistable {
    type Compatible = { def id: Long }
    implicit def obj2persistable(obj: Compatible) = new Persistable(obj)
  }
  class Persistable(val obj: Persistable.Compatible) {
    def persist() = println("Persisting: " + obj.id)
  }

  import Persistable.obj2persistable
  new Person().persist()
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's kinda irrelevant to the question.