# Update immutable data structure through inheritance

Tags: scala, immutability, scalaz, subtyping, lenses

I'm making a strategic game and I try to apply what I learned, try to use immutable data. In my game I have Units, these units can have different special function. By exemple some plane can hide themselves. What I search is a way to be able to do some sort of

```
abstract class Units {
val life:Int
}

trait Hidable { self: Units => 
val hided:Boolean
def hide:Units with Hidable= ....
}
```

without having to copy paste:

```
def hide = copy(hided=true)
```

on every case class that mixin Hidable.

Comment: So make it mutable, but only within the class, so you can change it.

Comment: I really need to return a new instance of Hidable.

Comment: Only metaprogramming with macros or toolboxes can help you, since the `copy` method of each case class is generated by compiler. You can learn more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373318/mixing-in-a-trait-dynamically

Comment: Better copy paste my function everywhere then :d

Answer (score 1):

A common way to update an immutable data structure -- is using [lenses](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/01/haskell-for-mainstream-programmers_28.html).
There's a [compiler plugin](https://github.com/gseitz/Lensed) to generate lenses for your code, though it is not very production-ready. It is also available for an old scalaz only.

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900307/cleaner-way-to-update-nested-structures).

Comment: I use the latest scalaz, and if it's to add manually a Lense for a single field, I better cp: copy :(

Comment: If you are to modify a single field, you'll get by with a `copy`. If at some point you end up updating a deeply nested structure, lenses are a way to go. You can modify that compiler plugin to generate lenses in a way, scalaz-seven specifies. The difference isn't than big:
the old way: https://gist.github.com/1404336#file_lens.scala,
the new way: https://github.com/folone/poi.scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/info/folone/scala/poi/package.scala#L49.
Or create a plugin of your own, using macros.