# Return type from scala method

Tags: scala

Is it possible in Scala to do something like this?

```
def getType(name:String) = {
  name match {
    case "MyObject" => MyObject.type
    ...
    case _ => throw new Exception("Unknown")
  }
}

type o = getType("MyObject")
```

Comment: For what purpose? What can you do with a type alias for an `object`?

Comment: try it yourself . did you get any issues?

Comment: I have a trait like this `trait TT{type T; val obj: T  }` which I mix to my class like this `val a = new A with  TT{type T=SomeSpecificType; val obj=someInstance}`.
And I want to do that dynamically.

Comment: Dynamic mixins are a problem too. You might be able to do it with macros, but it isn't going to be simple: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373318/mixing-in-a-trait-dynamically/10387200. Instead, why not `case "MyObject" => new A with TT { type T = MyObject.type; val obj = MyObject }; case "SomethingElse" => ...;` Fair warning, such types aren't that easy to use.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyRomanov .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. It just doesn't fit the grammar: `getType("MyObject")` is an expression and evaluates to a value; right-hand side of `type o =` must be a type.

In Scala, you can have types *depending* on values, but only in a specific way (path-dependent types), and this isn't one.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong - `type alias` is a compile time thing, whereas a function such as `getType(s: String)` will work at runtime. So any such alias allocation should not be possible even using if we can get the runtime type using reflection.