# factory method with mixins as type parameter

Tags: scala, types

I have two traits A and B where A's self type is B.

```
trait A {
    self: B =>
}

trait B
```

How would I now construct a factory method for implementations of Trait A with Trait B and its sub-types are taken as a type parameter like this?

```
def factory[T <: B](args): A with B
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic mixin in Scala - is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254232/dynamic-mixin-in-scala-is-it-possible)

Comment: Did you try `new A with B`? What is the question?

Comment: @Dima question is how to create a factory method for A with B and its subtypes taken as a type parameter which is already explained in the original question.

Comment: @LaloInDublin  I think this question and the other question is largely similar except in my case A and B are concrete types with B additionally type bounded. In the other case I presume A and B are unbounded types. If that is the case both the questions are significantly different but have commonality of dynamic mixin.

Comment: @mig-foxbat I would try expanding the question with some examples what is going to be constructed. Are there e.g. traits `trait B1 extends B` and `trait B2 extends B` and the factory is going to construct `A with B1` / `A with B2` ?