# Groovy Dynamic Object - How to properly reset properties?

Tags: grails, dynamic, groovy, metaprogramming, metaclass

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568397/groovy-dynamic-property-per-object) I created a Groovy class that will have dynamic properties.

```
class MyDynamic {
  def propertyMissing( String name, value ) {
    this.metaClass."$name" = value
    value
  }
}
```

So far all good, now I can set some non-existent property with success

```
MyDynamic dyna = new MyDynamic()
dyna.someProp = new Date()
```

My problem begins when I have another instance with the same name of property, but with another type

```
MyDynamic dyna2 = new MyDynamic()
dyna2.someProp = "0" //GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '0' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date'
```

Actually I need this because I'm creating objects with the result of a query without knowing the table and the column. I get the name of the column with the `ResultSetMetaData` and add the property to the instance of the dynamic object. Later I will use this object to export all the properties and values. In different tables I have the same column name, but with different types.

So my question is: how can I reset this metaClass when I'm done with the instance to not conflict with other instance?

Comment: That snippet is not working

Comment: Sorry, class was written "Class"

Comment: I fixed that, but it still doesn't work. What version are you using?

Comment: Can you be more specific with "doesn't work"? I'm using 2.0.7 that comes with Grails 2.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a [Expando](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/groovy-goodness-expando-as-dynamic-bean.html), a Map or a simple container:

```
class Dynamic {
  def properties = [:]
  void setProperty( String name, value ) {
    properties[name] = value
  }

  def getProperty(String property) { properties[property] }
}

d = new Dynamic()

d.name = "yeah"
assert d.name.class == String

d.name = new Date()
assert d.name.class == Date
```

Comment: Damn! I didn't know about Expando. Thanks!