# Java ScriptEngine - Create dynamic variables in java class

Tags: java, javascript-engine

I've using the java ScriptEngine to execute a script that could alter a shared Java class. I'm wondering, if it's possible to support dynamically created variables in the java class?

```
// create a script engine manager
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();

// create a JavaScript engine
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript"); 
engine.put("javaclass", jClass);

engine.eval("javaclass.propertyThatDoesNotExist = 'test'"); // throws exception
```

Answer (score 2):

You can *register* a javascript variable in the engine, by using the [ScriptEngine#put(String key, Object value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method. For example:

```
engine.put("i", 10);
```

This is how can you retrieve the registered variable:

```
int i = ((Double) engine.eval("i")).intValue();
System.out.println("JavaScript variable in Java; i = " + i);
```

Answer (score -1):

Java is not a dynamic language. So you can not add a property/variable to that class/object. For that you need to use a different language like Groovy or Java Script.

Comment: I tried the same code with groovy and it failed too with the same error (no public property). I used this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/6569565/1228906 and I was able to dynamically create properties in scripts but doing the same in the ScriptEngine fails. Thanks though!

Comment: I assume you used the "binding". You an not add a "property" to a "class" dynamicaly. You only can define dynamic global variables.